# Docusign Envelope Signed Event

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is there such thing for eventNotification envelopeEvents to have signed event? I'm using webhook.
I see 2 differents documentation here.

[image]

[image]

Basically I needed to know when the document has been signed, but it's not ready to be downloaded yet, so I can show that the document is in Pending State on the UI.

I need this, since if the user close the docusign page, it will count as, declined or void. So I can't use that event status to trigger any event.

Note:
I have it already working with webhook, for completed event.
It's just sometime after the user signed everything.. It takes up to 5 minutes for the document to be available from docusign (completed event). Thus I need some way to show the user on the UI, that it is already signed, but not available yet (PENDING state)

Comment: Are you using web-hook? I found similar discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49285247/248616

Comment: yes.. I am using webhook

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `signed` event, DocuSign uses the `Completed` event.

Why: `completed` covers the different situations for the different types of recipients--

- a `signer` recipient is `complete` when they sign the document.
- a `carbon copy` recipient is `complete` when the email with the copy is sent to the recipient.
- a `certified copy` recipient is `complete` when they positively acknowledge receipt of the copy.

Etc.

There are also two levels of webhook notification available to you:

- You can be notified when the entire envelope is `complete`. This is when all the signers for the envelope have signed.
- You can be notified when each individual recipient has `completed` their action. This means that you'll also be notified when non-signers have reached the complete status.
- You can also elect to receive both sets of notifications. (And more.)

Note that envelopes don't need to have any signers. You can examine the webhook notification message and/or interrogate the envelope's status to determine exact status after you've been notified via the webhook.